# Convert Culture.DateTimeFormat to HighChart's xDateFormat string

Tags: asp.net, highcharts

I have implemented highcharts in our asp.net application and in set tooltip as per below with dateformat attributes.

```
tooltip: {
             xDateFormat: '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S' 
             //xDateFormat: '<% = _DateFormat %>'                    
          }
```

Now i would like to display it according to end user's culture setting and for that made one function and property and set it in page load as per below

```
  _dateFormat = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S";// 
  //_dateFormat = General.GetUserCulture().DateTimeFormat ; how to convert to above format
```

In above case how can i convert culture's datetimeformat to highchart's datetimeformat string?

**Update**

For HighChart Following are list of format pattern

- %a: Short weekday, like 'Mon'.
- %A: Long weekday, like 'Monday'.
- %d: Two digit day of the month, 01 to 31.
- %e: Day of the month, 1 through 31.
- %b: Short month, like 'Jan'.
- %B: Long month, like 'January'.
- %m: Two digit month number, 01 through 12.
- %y: Two digits year, like 09 for 2009.
- %Y: Four digits year, like 2009.
- %H: Two digits hours in 24h format, 00 through 23.
- %I: Two digits hours in 12h format, 00 through 11.
- %l (Lower case L): Hours in 12h format, 1 through 11.
- %M: Two digits minutes, 00 through 59.
- %p: Upper case AM or PM.
- %P: Lower case AM or PM.
- %S: Two digits seconds, 00 through 59

So if i will do with replace (as per @Ruchit answer here) then after i can not achieve what i am expected because if you consider below code then it is true for one formatand wrong for another

```
_dateFormat = format.ShortDatePattern + " " + format.LongTimePattern;
                _dateFormat = _dateFormat.Replace("yyyy", "%Y")
                                         .Replace("yy", "%y")
                                         .Replace("MMMM", "%B")
                                         .Replace("MMM", "%b")
                                         .Replace("MM", "%m")
                                         .Replace("M", "%m")
                                         .Replace("dddd", "%A")
                                         .Replace("ddd", "%a")
                                         .Replace("dd", "%d")
                                         .Replace("HH", "%H")
                                         .Replace("mm", "%M")
                                         .Replace("ss", "%S");
```

So i would like to find generalize solution for this which will work with all format. Help me if anyone found something helpfull!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use following code to get the string format of the culture of your current thread.

```
    System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo format =
         System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat;
string strFormat = format.ShortDatePattern + " " + 
         format.ShortTimePattern;
```

Once you do this you will have datetime format string like `M/d/yyyy h:mm tt`. Once you get this you can use replace function for string. You can use `strFormat.Replace("M","%m").Replace("d","%d")` and so on.
You can use this variable with inline code on the design page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It helped me however it is not possible with every format because it can contain MMM , MM , M etc for month and same way for year, day and time format